# How to Override the Shipping Method Management Model

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I need to override the **shippingmethodmagament.php** file which is in the model file in the magento this path **vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement.php**

but the interfaces is applied in this file and i have try with the preference but its not properly work

I need to override this function inside the my custom module model please help me out to override this core function
[image]

Comment: Try using this link it may help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/270381/how-to-override-model-in-magento2

Comment: @Asssd i need to override the getShippingMethods function which is inside this model and that function is a private function

Comment: using prefrence will resolve it in above link there were multiple ways plugin and prefrence as you need it for private funciton use prefrence.

Comment: preference is not worked on the interface class

Comment: What do you mean by "preference is not worked" ?  Note that after modifying a constructor (what you are doing with a preference) you need to do a `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: I have updated my question please check

Comment: I still don't get what is your issue with the interface is applied ? Looks like the class implements `\Magento\Quote\Api\ShippingMethodManagementInterface,
     \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagementInterface,
     \Magento\Quote\ModelShipmentEstimationInterface`

Then your extended class will also implements these interfaces, what is the issue with that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is some magento basics that you are missing there.

What you are probably looking for is called preference.

You need to write a preference in the `di.xml` of your custom module
Just replace with the correct path

## di.xml

```
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\..\ShippingMethodManagement" type="Your_Module_Namespace\...\ShippingMethodManagement" />
</config>
```

Then you can write your own ShippingMethodManagement that extends the magento one.

Comment: I have updated my question please check